# Favorite tags highlighting

Tags: discussion

When we choose one or more favorite tags, the posts containing those tags get highlighted.

But the color they use (light blue) isn't very noticeable. 
Is there a way to make it darker or something,so that it stands out?

Comment: You can change this for yourself using a User Style Sheet. Which browser do you use?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no method to change it in the system. However, if you can program, you could try to program an extension to change it for you.

Aside from that, you can write a [feature request](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/give-feedback).